# Where to find the asp.net compiled executable in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, publishing, visual-web-developer-2010

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I have created a WCF service in the website. The application is running fine in IDE. But I want to publish the code to IIS.

I tried the Publish option, but in VWD express edition Publish option is not there. So I want to manually copy the compiled code to IIS. But I couldn't find the compiled code in the `Bin` or `ClientBin` folder.

How I can get the compiled code? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to copy the aspx files into your IIS webserver.

Comment: If you copy all the source over then it'll be compiled by IIS into a temporary assembly and run from there.